# How get result to UI Thread from an android kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-runonuithread

I didn't understand how kotlin coroutines work.
I need to do a long work on an asynchronous thread and get the result on the UI Thread in an Android app.
Can someone give me some examples?
For example

```
private fun getCountries(){
        viewModelScope.launch { 
            val a = model.getAllCountries()
            countriesList.value = a
        }
}
```

will lunch model.getAllCountries() async but in the end how can i get result to UI Thread?

Comment: Regardless of what scope you launch your coroutines from, you can always execute code on the UI thread by using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`, so for example:
  
    private fun getCountries(){
            viewModelScope.launch { 
                val a = model.getAllCountries()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    countriesList.value = a
                }
            }
    }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well! Adding to @ianhanniballake's answer,

In your function,

```
private fun getCountries(){
   // 1
   viewModelScope.launch {  
      val a = model.getAllCountries()
      countriesList.value = a
   }
}
```

1. You have launched your `suspend` function from viewModel scope, and the default context is the main thread.

Now the thread on which `suspend fun getAllCountries` will work will be specified in the definition of `getAllCountries` function.

So it can be written something like

```
suspend fun getAllCountries(): Countries {
   // 2
   return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    service.getCountries()
   }
}
```

2. We specify a new thread to call the server using `withContext`, and after return from `withContext` block, we are back on main thread.

Comment: So if i want run getAllCountries on async i must use return withContext(Disptachers.IO) ?

Comment: Yes :) Using withContext(), you specify the context(thread) of the operation.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation for `viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#viewmodelscope):

> This scope is bound to [Dispatchers.Main.immediate](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/immediate.html)

Where `Dispatchers.Main` is the Kotlin way of saying 'the main thread'. This means that, by default, all of the code in the `launch` block runs on the main thread. Your `getAllCountries()`, if it wants to run on a different thread, would want to use `withContext(Disptachers.IO)` to move to the IO coroutine dispatcher, as an example.

Therefore in this case, the result of your method is *already* on the main thread and there's nothing else you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to do a long work on an asynchronous thread

There's no such thing as an asynchronous thread, actually. Whether your network operations are sync or async gets decided by the implementation of the network API you're using.

If you have a blocking network operation, it will stay blocking even when you apply coroutines. The value of coroutines for that use case is limited to making it a bit easier to transfer the result back to the UI thread.

You achieve this by launching a coroutine with the UI dispatcher (the default) and then switching to a thread pool to perform a blocking operation without blocking the UI thread:

```
    viewModelScope.launch { 
        countriesList.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            model.getAllCountries()
        }
    }
```

Note that a thread inside the thread pool underlying the `IO` dispatcher will still be blocked, so in terms of the usage of system resources this doesn't make a difference. There will be as many blocked native threads as there are concurrent network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to post your result within a `MutableLiveData` inside your ViewModel class and observe the LiveData in your view.

Your **ViewModel** class:

```kotlin
class CountriesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val parentJob = Job()
    val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default
    val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
    val countries: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Country>> = MutableLiveData()
    val model = MyModel()

    fun getCountries(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val countriesList = model.getAllCountries()
            countries.postValue(countries)
        }
    }
}
```

Your **view** class (E.g. a fragment)

```kotlin
class CountriesFragment : Fragment(){
        private lateinit var countriesVM : CountriesViewModel
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            countriesVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CountriesViewModel::class.java)
            // calling api in your view model here
            countriesVM.getCountries()
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            // observer is notified of the changes on countries livedata
            countriesVM.countries.observe(this, Observer { countries ->
                // Update ui here
                updateUI(countries)
            })
        }
    }
```